# Mostrar detalles desde mysql con botón en PHP

Tags: php, html, subconsultas, html-tabla

Necesito averiguar la forma de añadir un botón de "Detalles", para al clickar ver los detalles completos del cliente.

```
            $strHTML='<table>
                            <thead>
                                <th >Codigo</th>
                                <th >Agente Comercial</th>
                                <th >Óptica</th>
                                <th >Provincia</th>
                                <th >Contacto</th>
                                <th >Correo</th>
                                <th >Teléfono</th>
                                <th >Detalles</th>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>';

            foreach ($arrResultado as $row)
            {
                $strHTML.='<tr>';
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["id"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["asignaragente"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["ncomercial"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["provincia"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["nombre"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["email"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["telefono"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["Boton Detalles"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='</tr>';

            }

            $strHTML.='</tbody>';
            $strHTML.='</table>';
```

De esta forma, poder acceder a ver una ficha de un cliente.
No consigo añadir nada, que no sea un $row, me salta error en el php.

Comment: Para agregar el boton que necesitas podes usar el boton  submit del form https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

Comment: Buenas tardes Patrick. El problema que me aclaro al añadirlo en esta linea, sin que me salga error de php  $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["Boton Detalles"]."</td>";

Comment: ¿De dónde sale `$row`? Parecería que es de una consulta a una base de datos, donde tener un nombre de columna con espacios en blanco es posible pero tampoco muy común. ¿Seguro que es "Boton Detalles" y no "BotonDetalles" o algo parecido?

Comment: Este código me parece familiar. En el bucle tú estas leyendo filas de un conjunto de resultados, y el botón no pertenece a ese conjunto de resultados que proviene de la base de datos, sino que es un elemento externo. Puedes cambiar esta línea: `$strHTML.='<td>'.$row["Boton Detalles"]."</td>";` por esto: **`$strHTML.='<td><button id="detalles">Ver detalle</button></td>';`** y luego por Javascript o jQuery puedes *escuchar*  los clicks de tu botón mediante `#detalles`,  o sea, mediante su id.

Comment: Buenas tardes A.Cedano, estoy seguro de que te resulta familiar! Como siempre +1 muchísimas gracias de nuevo aclararme de nuevo el problema y darle solución!!!